# split string into columns

Tags: regex, r, string, strsplit

I have a column of values that are little messy

```
   Col1
   ----------------------------------------
   B-Lipotropin(S)...............874 BTETLS
   IgE-Dandelion(S).............4578 BTETLS
   Beta Gamma-Globulin..........2807 BTETLS
   Lactate, P
   Phospholipid .........8296 BTETLS
```

How do I split these values into three columns like this

```
    Col1                        Col2         Col3
    -----------------------------------------------
    B-Lipotropin(S)             874          BTETLS
    IgE-Dandelion(S)            4578         BTETLS
    Beta Gamma-Globulin         2807         BTETLS
    Lactate, P
    Phospholipid                8296         BTETLS
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you give a dput() on your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `tidyr` for this:

```
library(tidyr)

dat <- read.table(text="B-Lipotropin(S)...............874 BTETLS
IgE-Dandelion(S).............4578 BTETLS
Beta Gamma-Globulin..........2807 BTETLS
Lactate, P
Phospholipid .........8296 BTETLS",
sep=";", stringsAsFactors=F, col.names = 'Col1')

dat %>%
  separate(Col1, c('Col1', 'Col2'), '\\.+', extra = 'drop') %>%
  separate(Col2, c('Col2', 'Col3'), ' ', extra = 'drop')

#                                    Col1 Col2   Col3
# 1                       B-Lipotropin(S)  874 BTETLS
# 2                      IgE-Dandelion(S) 4578 BTETLS
# 3                   Beta Gamma-Globulin 2807 BTETLS
# 4                            Lactate, P <NA>   <NA>
# 5                         Phospholipid  8296 BTETLS
```

**edit**: you can also do it in one step with `separate(Col1, paste0('Col', 1:3), '([^,] )|(\\.+)', extra = 'drop')`

Answer (score 2):

Without the actual data, it is difficult to give a general solution. However, below is one using regular expressions.

Here I assumed that the first two columns are always separated by at least one `.`, possibly with spaces before or after; the second and third column are presumably separated by spaces.

```
dat <- read.table(text="B-Lipotropin(S)...............874 BTETLS
IgE-Dandelion(S).............4578 BTETLS
Beta Gamma-Globulin..........2807 BTETLS
Lactate, P
Phospholipid .........8296 BTETLS",
sep=";", stringsAsFactors=F)

# separate first column
l <- strsplit(dat[,1], split="[[:space:]]*\\.+[[:space:]]*")
l <- lapply(l, function(x) c(x,rep("",2-length(x))))
l <- do.call(rbind,l)

dat <- cbind(dat, l[,1])

# separate last two columns
l <- strsplit(l[,2], split="[[:space:]]+")
l <- lapply(l, function(x) c(x,rep("",2-length(x))))
l <- do.call(rbind,l)

dat <- cbind(dat, l)
colnames(dat) <- c("original","col1","col2","col3")
```

The separated columns look like this:

```
> dat[,-1]
                 col1 col2   col3
1     B-Lipotropin(S)  874 BTETLS
2    IgE-Dandelion(S) 4578 BTETLS
3 Beta Gamma-Globulin 2807 BTETLS
4          Lactate, P            
5        Phospholipid 8296 BTETLS
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R with a regex to split the string in the right places.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(                                         # coerce to data.frame
    do.call(rbind,                                              # bind list
            lapply(
                strsplit(dat$Col1, "\\.+|[0-9]+(?= )", perl=T), # split messy string
                `length<-`, 3)                                  # normalize lengths of lists
            )
), paste0("Col", 1:3))                                          # add column names

#                  Col1 Col2   Col3
# 1     B-Lipotropin(S)  874 BTETLS
# 2    IgE-Dandelion(S) 4578 BTETLS
# 3 Beta Gamma-Globulin 2807 BTETLS
# 4          Lactate, P <NA>   <NA>
# 5       Phospholipid  8296 BTETLS
```